# Why are my errors getting buried with Kapt and Kotlin? How do I increase the error limit?

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, kotlin, kapt

I am having issues involving Android Data Binding, Room, and Dagger. All of these generate code with errors at compile-time showing objects as not found if any code generation step fails. This can result in many, many errors. The number of errors can exceed the Java error limit.

As a result, the root cause error is getting buried. It's not visible in the list of errors.

Increasing the Java error limit is not working because the Kotlin annotation processor Kapt ignores it. How do I increase the Java error limit?

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer here: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#java-compiler-options

One needs to add the following block to the build.gradle file:

```
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        // Increase the max count of errors from annotation processors.
        // Default is 100.
        option("-Xmaxerrs", 500)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried a couple of different tips on how to increase the error limit. But this one is finally working. You saved a plenty of hours in our project man. Huge thanks :)